# Errorno 2 No such file or directyory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, opencsv, import-csv

[Calcul**your text**ating total months - CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWN1r.png)
Iimportedd csv file correctly. I even received a path after adding csvpath.Trying toocalculatedg the total number of months in the CSVs file, now getting errorno 2, no such file or directory with the file link I tried to access.

Comment: **DO NOT** post your code as screenshots. They are hard to read and we can't copy/paste the text in the image. Having said the error is pretty clear. The path `..\Resources\budget_data.csv` does not exist or you do not have read permission. Since you're running this in Ipython one likely explanation is the PWD of that process is not what you expect and therefore your relative path is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You can verify your full path using `os.path.abspath()` function:

```
import os
csvpath = os.path.join('..', 'Resources', 'budget-data.csv')
os.path.abspath(csvpath)
```

This way you will get full path of desired csv file and you can check whether it's right path or not.

Check below screenshot:
[image: Ipython Screenshot]